# Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm getting this when I want to submit my form:

`Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)`

I have enabled in php.ini - `php_fileinfo extension`. I also restarted my localhost server.

This is my rule: `'img_1' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg',`

This is what I get when I submit form:

`at MimeTypeGuesser->guess('C:\xampp\tmp\php2490.tmp') in File.php line 79`

This is how I uploading image:

```
public function storeAuction(AuctionSubmitRequest $request)
{   
    $product = Product::create($request->all());

if(Input::hasfile('img_1'))
{
$request->file('img_1')->move(public_path('images'), $request->file('img_1')->getClientOriginalName());

$product->img_1 = 'images' . $request->file('img_1')->getClientOriginalName();
}

    $product->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $product->save();
    return redirect('/');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to comment out the following line from your php.ini and then restart your apache

> extension=php_fileinfo.dll

Answer (score 0):

You can "hack" this problem by creating an Enum class that will check if mimes is accurate

```
<?php

namespace App\Support\Enum;

enum ImageExtension: string {
    case Png = 'png';
    case Jpg = 'jpg';
    case Jpeg = 'jpeg';

    /**
     * Return all values as array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function values()
    {
        return array_map(
            fn(ImageExtension $imageExtension) => $imageExtension->value,
            self::cases()
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your request just check it like this

```
['image', 'mimes:' . implode(',', ImageExtension::values()), 'max:10000'],
```